# Table Numbering And Caption in Same location

Tags: tables, formatting, captions, tabularx

My table and caption are located on the same line and this started happening after I used a different class file for the conference I am applying towards.

Here is a picture of what I mean:
(Normally the words "Table 1" go above the caption, not on the same line)
[image]

I was wondering what could be some reason for this? What should I look for in the class file to see if this was on purpose or my mistake?

Comment: Major document elements (including floats and their captions) are governed by the document class. Some packages extend this (most notably the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption)), but it is to be expected that a change in class could lead to this. If you provide more detail with regards to the old and new class, one can suggest alternatives to regain the old look.

Comment: Here is the link for the new class: http://www.epapers.org/iscas2014/ESR/images/windows_latex_template.zip

Comment: Here is the link to the old class document: http://iscas2013.epapers.org/ESR/images/IEEEtran.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [old document class](http://iscas2013.epapers.org/ESR/images/IEEEtran.zip) differs from the [new document class](http://www.epapers.org/iscas2014/ESR/images/windows_latex_template.zip) in how it defined `\@makecaption` - the macro responsible for setting the caption of floats. Here's the difference:

#### Old document class:

```
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  % test if is a for a figure or table
  \ifx\@captype\@IEEEtablestring%
    % if a table, do table caption
    \footnotesize\bgroup\par
      \centering\@IEEEtabletopskipstrut{\normalfont\footnotesize #1}\\
      {\normalfont\footnotesize\scshape #2}\par\addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}\egroup%
    \@IEEEtablecaptionsepspace
  % if not a table, format it as a figure
  \else
  %...
  \fi}
```

#### New document class:

```
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  % test if is a for a figure or table
  \ifx\@captype\@IEEEtablestring%
    % if a table, do table caption
    \footnotesize{\centering\normalfont\footnotesize#1.\qquad\scshape #2\par}%
    \@IEEEtablecaptionsepspace
  % if not a table, format it as a figure
  \else
  %...
  \fi}
```

It's obvious that the older class inserts a line break `\\` while the newer uses `.\qquad` to separate the caption type and text. It suffices to use [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to patch `\@makecaption` to insert a `\par` (paragraph break) instead of using `.\qquad`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}% <cmd>
  {.\qquad}% <search>
  {\par}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \caption{Filled with some text}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

`\patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}` searches for `<search>` in `<cmd>` and replaces it with `<replace>`. If this search-and-replace is successful, `<success>` is executed, otherwise `<failure>` is.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am going to contact the conference contacts to make sure there isn't an error.